# How to offset content under a navbar when using height:100%?

Tags: css

Consider the following code:

HTML
    menu

CSS

```
#menu {
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:50px
}

#wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;    
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I want the wrapper to sit beneath the fixed nav, and scroll all the contents. The effect is that the scrollbar starts from below the nav instead of above it.

However, because of the `top:50px` offset, the bottom of the wrapper is 50px off the screen. How can I fix this and still have it 100% height of remaining screen estate?

**IMPORTANT: I need this to be IE8 compatible**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll work with a slightly different approach:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkUc9/)

```
#wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your both divs (#menu and #wrapper) with a div then apply position fixed to that div and now apply the position relative to both divs (#menu and #wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Just use bottom: 0; top: 50px;

```
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: blue;
}
#content {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: red;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLHLC/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this with,

```
position:fixed;
height:100%;
top:50px;
```

since you given position:fixed,it was not relative to any container, just the viewport only, so top:50px with 100% height, will always be off the screen.

alter any of these, you can do this, something like giving the height and top in '%'

```
position:fixed;
height:90%;
top:10%;
```

also

```
 #menu {
   height:10%
}
```